# How to prevent executing wp cron on every page visit?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have scheduled a wp cron

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
wp_schedule_event($time, 'daily', 'loyality_expiry_notification');
add_action('loyality_expiry_notification', 'send_notification');
function send_notification() {...}
```

`send_notification` sends email notification daily.But i am receiving email on every page visit.
I want to execute this event only once in a day.

Answer (score 1):

`!wp_next_scheduled` did the job.

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'loyality_expiry_notification' ) ) {
     wp_schedule_event($time, 'daily', 'loyality_expiry_notification');
}
```